# array.find() function doesnt work inside promise

Tags: javascript, typescript

hi I want to send a request and save the result into an array then check if that result has existed so I don't send the same request again I've done it with a separate array but the problem is that the find function doesn't get fired at all I tryed for loop but that didnt't work too what am I doing wrong

```
   async call(p: UserOrdersParams): Promise<OrderWithCheckoutWithPagination> {
    try {
        const orders = await this.orderRepo.getOrders({page: p.page, perPage: p.perPage});
        const savedProducts = new Array<ProductFullRes>()
        const {results} = await PromisePool
            .for(orders.orders)
            .withConcurrency(5)
            .process(async (e) => {
                let temp = savedProducts.find((t) => {
                    return (t.id === e.id)
                });
                if (temp === undefined) {
                    temp = await this.productRepo.getProductById(e.product_id);
                    savedProducts.push(temp)
                }
                const checkout = await this.orderRepo.getOrderCheckout(e.id);
                return {
                    order: e,
                    checkout: checkout,
                    product: temp
                } as OrdersWithCheckout;

            })
        return {
            orders: results,
            pagination: {
                meta: orders.meta,
                links: orders.links
            }

        }
    } catch
        (e) {
        return Promise.reject(new NetworkFailure((e as Exception).codeMessage, (e as Exception).code));
    }
}
```

temp is always undefined and I test it without the promis_pool package and tried it with promise. all and with an async map function too but I can't use array methods can even console.log inside that functions

Comment: are you saying the callback to `.process` isn't running? - oh, wait ... `savedProducts` is an empty array so of course `.find` won't run on an empty array

Comment: yes but after another request product gonna be added and it won't be empty so why it doesn't run even I tried using for loop for checking but it doesn't execute that loop

Comment: if that code is called every time another product is added, then of course the array is going to be empty, since that code empties the array - `const savedProducts = new Array<ProductFullRes>()` runs EVERY time that code runs

Comment: no this code is inside one async function that array is not empty and not be initialized every time the code inside process is called every time i also checked with console log

Comment: no, the code you posted doesn't look that way, and just before `const { results } = await PromisePool` the array is cleared ... EVERY time